# Working with redis-graph

Tags: graph, redis, shortest-path, redisgraph

I'm a beginner in redis-graph and presently I'm working on K-shortest path algorithm which is implemented in JAVA(where a graph is created using hashmap) and as the dataset is quite large(27 million rows) I need to a database to store a graph and for the same reason I plan to use  redis-graph, but redis-graph uses cypher query language. How can integrate both these applications?
Any other suggestion(s) would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use RedisGraph to hold the graph for you at the moment there's no way of finding K shortest paths from node A to node B, I've implemented a shortest path algorithm within RedisGraph but have yet to expose it to clients, I'm not sure of the approach you had in mind for finding K shortest paths, *I've implemented one using a cost edge flow-network, you can find my javascript implementation [here](https://github.com/orcaman/flownetwork)

I'll might include a k-shortest path algo within RedisGraph, I need some time to think about that, in any case, using the current sub-set of Cypher supported by RedisGraph finding K shortest path is not possible,

You'll might be able to retrieve a relevant sub-graph from RedisGraph to your Java application find path I out of K and once no additional paths can be found, extend that sub-graph be retrieving additional nodes / edges from RedisGraph.

Comment: @user284194 I think I know who you are IRL, but it maybe good to add some info to your SO profile to help others ;)

Comment: @ user284194 I'm using YEN Algorithm to find k-shortest path